# Scene Change Crash in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am having a problem when trying to push a button and going to the next scene. I get the SIGABRT error. I don't know what the problem is:

```
[...]
    //Play Button
    CCMenuItem *playbutton;
    playbutton = [CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:@"Play" target:self selector:@selector(playButtonMeathod:)];

    CMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:itemAchievement,playbutton,itemLeaderboard, nil];

    [menu alignItemsHorizontallyWithPadding:20];
    [menu setPosition:ccp( size.width/2, size.height/2 - 50)];

    // Add the menu to the layer
    [self addChild:menu];

    -(void)playButtonMeathod{
    // Create a scene transition that uses the "RotoZoom" effect

    CCTransitionRotoZoom *transition = [CCTransitionRotoZoom transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[Level_1 scene]];



    // Tell the director to run the transition

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:transition];

[...]
```

Comment: Show us the implementation of `playButtonMeathod`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One issue might be that the method signature is incorrect in your CCMenuItemFont selector target. Try:

`CCMenuItemFont *playbutton = [CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:@"Play" target:self selector:@selector(playButtonMeathod)];`

Comment: i have found where the error is, it is at the   [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[Level_1 scene2] ]];
    
but idk how to fix it...